# Does the average of random numbers in [0,1] converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-walk, random, average

(sorry if this is obvious or it has already been answered)

If you generate a lot of random (uniformly distributed) values between 0 and 1 and take the average, the answer gets closer and closer to 0.5. But can you actually say that the average converges after an infinite amount of numbers? I couldn't think of the answer to this, because I thought

- Since it's uniformly distributed, obviously the average should approach 0.5
- It includes randomness, so technically speaking, every number could be 0.7 and it wouldn't converge to 0.5

Comment: When dealing with infinities in probability (as in, a variable that can take infinitely many values, or infinitely many variables), something important to remember is that *events with probability zero are not impossible*. In this case, although it’s technically conceivable that the average is always $0.7$, the averages will converge to $0.5$ with probability $1$. Look up the strong law of large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the law of large numbers the sample mean will approach the true expected value as the sample size increases.

[Law of Large Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urENS.png)

Comment: It will do so almost surely.